# Time Complexity with increasing queue size

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I've searched Google and StackOverflow for the past half hour or so, and, while I've found a lot of interesting information, I have yet to find the solution to my problem. I think this should be fairly simple to answer; I just don't know how to answer it.

I'm using the following loop in a program I'm working on (this is pseudocode of my algorithm, obviously):

```
while Q is not empty
    x = Q.dequeue()
    for(i = 1 to N)
        if x.s[i] = 0
            y = Combine(x, i)
            Q.add(G[y])
```

In this loop:

- *Q* is a queue
- *x* is an object with that contains an integer array *s*
- *N* is an integer representing the problem size
- *y* is a new instance of the same type of object as *x*
- *Combine* is a method that returns a new object of the same type as *x*

  - *Combine* only contains a For loop, so it has a worst-case time complexity of O(N)

My question is how I should be trying to calculate the time complexity of this loop. Because I'm potentially adding *N-1* items to the queue on each loop, I'm assuming that it will increase the complexity beyond just the simple O(N) from a normal loop.

If you need any more information to help me with this, please let me know and I'll get you what I can when I can.

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is "how many items can be added to the queue *in total*?" Typically in a breadth-first search algorithm such as this one, the potential number of child items added in a single loop iteration is not a reliable guide to the total number of items. Once you establish the item count, you need to analyze the cost of processing a single item (here, the cost would be Combine, which you say is O(N)).

Comment: After beating my head against a wall for most of the weekend, I got a few other guys to help me look at it, and we ended up determining that you can add N! items to the queue. A detail I forgot to mention above is that the integer array *s* is of length N. That probably would have been good information to put in there from the start, but I wasn't thinking clearly.

Thanks for your help!